# ChartWrapper : "Cannot read property 'count' of undefined"

Tags: gwt, google-visualization, jsni

I have a strange problem when I want to work with the ChartWrapper of Google Visualization API, I work with smartgwt and JSNI methods to put the chart into a window, I succeeded with the normal chart (PieChart, LineChart ...) but with the ChartWrapper I have an error that I can't resolve :

```
"Cannot read property 'count' of undefined"
```

and there's no property in ChartWrapper call 'count'

I use the exemple of the tutoriel

```
google.load('visualization', '1');   // Don't need to specify chart libraries!
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
function drawVisualization() {
    var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'ColumnChart',
      dataTable: [['', 'Germany', 'USA', 'Brazil', 'Canada', 'France', 'RU'],
                  ['', 700, 300, 400, 500, 600, 800]],
      options: {'title': 'Countries'},
      containerId: 'vis_div'
    });
    wrapper.draw();
  }
```

I also was trying to draw a ChartEditor(I use a simple example from the official page) but I have also the same error :